# Agregue un dataframe después de otro pero aumente el índice

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo una [dataframe original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D-WhqHn4mPPSXbBDdk-cB7bdllLcK8W-/view?usp=sharing) y [una otra que me gustaría añadir al primero](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GbwVvBIng4nDSoKN3sTtPBy0xU09DjTY/view?usp=sharing). Sin embargo, hay una columna con las identificaciones y me gustaría que el marco de datos que las filas del marco de datos que añadimos a ella para aumentar desde el mayor QID de la primera dataframe. Sé como agregar un marco de datos después de otro. Los nombres de las columnas de la segunda se incluyen en la primera.

```
df_qb.append(dfgrouped)
```

Hasta hoy intenté obtener el maximo en la columna QID de la dataframe original.

```
# get highest QID and start the QID of the appended rows from here
max_qid = df_qb.QID.astype(dtype = int, errors = 'ignore').max()
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-03bff1b7ef93> in <module>
      1 # get highest QID and start the QID of the appended rows from here
----> 2 max_qid = df_qb.QID.astype(dtype = int, errors = 'ignore').max()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in stat_func(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11213             return self._agg_by_level(name, axis=axis, level=level, skipna=skipna)
  11214         return self._reduce(
> 11215             f, name, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, numeric_only=numeric_only
  11216         )
  11217 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _reduce(self, op, name, axis, skipna, numeric_only, filter_type, **kwds)
   3889                 )
   3890             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 3891                 return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
   3892 
   3893         # TODO(EA) dispatch to Index

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py in f(values, axis, skipna, **kwds)
    123                     result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    124             else:
--> 125                 result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    126 
    127             return result

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py in reduction(values, axis, skipna, mask)
    835                 result = np.nan
    836         else:
--> 837             result = getattr(values, meth)(axis)
    838 
    839         result = _wrap_results(result, dtype, fill_value)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amax(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     28 def _amax(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     29           initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 30     return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     31 
     32 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es `int(df_qb.QID)`, ocurre que `df_qb.QID` no es una cadena, es una `Serie`, es decir el conjunto de todas las cadenas de la columna `QID`, y obviamente `int` no funciona. Para convertir a enteros la serie y calcular el máximo:

```
df_qb.QID.astype(dtype = int, errors = 'ignore').max()
```

Esto funcionará siempre que las cadenas sean "convertibles" a un entero.

Comment: Muchas gracias para su respuesta. Sin embargo hay pocas QID que estan alfanumericos. ¿Como puedo ignorarlos?

Comment: Se puede agregar errors = 'ignore'